# Making predictions on live video feed using React Native and Tensorflow.js

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have setup my react native app done all the installations and configurations of unimodules and packages are working as expected. No problem with dependency etc.

Now I want to implement a tensorflow model that I've trained from teachablemachine by google and I couldn't understand how to use it with camera because I'd like to process the frames from real time just like tensorflow react native api docs say.
This is a code I found online and I will change it with my model but the problem is it only detects the model when user takes picture. I want my camera to understand model in real time just like face detection, barcode scanner.

Main.js

```js
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

import {
  getModel,
  convertBase64ToTensor,
  startPrediction,
} from '../../helpers/tensor-helper';

import {Camera} from 'expo-camera';

import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import {
  cameraWithTensors,
  bundleResourceIO,
} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

const Main = () => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState();
  const [prediction, setPredictions] = useState();
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  let requestAnimationFrameId = 0;
  let frameCount = 0;
  let makePredictionsEveryNFrame = 1;

  const modelJson = require('../../model/model.json');
  const modelWeights = require('../../model/weights.bin');

  const getModel = async () => {
    try {
      await tf.ready();
      const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
        bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights),
      );
      return model;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Could not load model', error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setModel(getModel());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameId);
    };
  }, [requestAnimationFrameId]);

  const handleCameraStream = tensors => {
    if (!tensors) {
      console.log('Image not found!');
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrame === 0) {
        const imageTensor = tensors.next().value;
        if (model) {
          const results = await startPrediction(model, imageTensor);
          setPredictions(results);
          console.log(`prediction: ${JSON.stringify(prediction)}`);
        }
        tf.dispose(tensors);
      }
      frameCount += 1;
      frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrame;
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    console.log(`prediction: ${JSON.stringify(prediction)}`);

    loop();
    console.log(`prediction: ${JSON.stringify(prediction)}`);
  };

  let textureDims;
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1920,
      width: 1080,
    };
  } else {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1200,
      width: 1600,
    };
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TensorCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        // Standard Camera props
        style={styles.camera}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
        flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
        // Tensor related props
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={50}
        resizeWidth={50}
        resizeDepth={3}
        onReady={tensors => handleCameraStream(tensors)}
        autorender={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
};



export default Main;
```

tensorhelper.js:

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {bundleResourceIO, decodeJpeg} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import * as tfc from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';

import {Base64Binary} from '../utils/utils';
const BITMAP_DIMENSION = 224;

const modelJson = require('../model/model.json');
const modelWeights = require('../model/weights.bin');

// 0: channel from JPEG-encoded image
// 1: gray scale
// 3: RGB image
const TENSORFLOW_CHANNEL = 3;

export const getModel = async () => {
  try {
    await tf.ready();
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
      bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights),
    );
    return model;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Could not load model', error);
  }
};

export const convertBase64ToTensor = async base64 => {
  try {
    const uIntArray = Base64Binary.decode(base64);
    // decode a JPEG-encoded image to a 3D Tensor of dtype
    const decodedImage = decodeJpeg(uIntArray, 3);
    // reshape Tensor into a 4D array
    return decodedImage.reshape([
      1,
      BITMAP_DIMENSION,
      BITMAP_DIMENSION,
      TENSORFLOW_CHANNEL,
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Could not convert base64 string to tesor', error);
  }
};

export const startPrediction = async (model, tensor) => {
  try {
    // predict against the model
    const output = await model.predict(tensor);
    // return typed array

    return tfc.tensor().dataSync();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error predicting from tesor image', error);
  }
};
```

I edited files and get this as output:

````
 LOG  prediction: undefined
 LOG  prediction: undefined
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: When using targetShape.depth=3, targetShape.width must be a multiple of 4. Alternatively do not call detectGLCapabilities()
fromTexture@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:267911:24
nextFrameGenerator$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:268598:67  
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26537:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26710:32
loop$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:126503:43
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26537:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26710:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26537:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26610:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26640:19
tryCallTwo@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:31390:9
doResolve@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:31554:25
Promise@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:31413:14
callInvokeWithMethodAndArg@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26639:33
enqueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26644:157
async@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26661:69
loop@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:126494:42
handleCameraStream@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:126535:11   
onReady@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:126572:34
onGLContextCreate$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:268641:37   
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26537:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26710:32   
__callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3317:35       
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3096:34
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3300:15
flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.AppName&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3095:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]```
````

Comment: Does my answer solve it?

Comment: yes the real time camera part it did (the onReady props) but for some reason my tensorflow model could not be loaded,  does your answer change upon different models? or am i making a mistake here?

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I did this awhile back(last year) so I might have forgotten something but you can just refer to the code [here](https://github.com/yudhiesh/Driver-Drowsiness-App/blob/master/screens/CameraView.js), uses Expo and makes predictions on a live video feed just pardon the really bad code(I write better code now).

Anyway this a simple update on what you need to do which is mainly about `handleCameraStream()`. You will need to run two different `useEffect` hooks, one for initially loading up the model and the other one for canceling the animation frames which you will need to use when make predictions constantly.

Set the model into state then you can access it using `model` from any part in the file. I also did the same for `predictions`.

I have also added the ability to make predictions every `N` number of frames , by setting `makePredictionsEveryNFrames` to `1` it basically passes the tensors from `TensorCamera` to the function to make predictions every single frame. After making predictions you will also want to dispose of the tensors using `tf.dispose()`. This function `loop()` needs to be run infinitely to make predictions on oncoming frames continuously.

```
const Main = () => {
  const [model, setModel] = useState();
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState();

  let requestAnimationFrameId = 0;
  let frameCount = 0;
  let makePredictionsEveryNFrames = 1;

  useEffect(() => {
    setModel(await getModel());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameId);
    };
  }, [requestAnimationFrameId]);

  const handleCameraStream = (tensors) => {
    if (!tensors) {
      console.log("Image not found!");
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrame === 0) {
        const imageTensor = tensors.next().value;
        if (model) {
          const results = await startPrediction(model, imageTensor);
          setPredictions(results);
        }
        tf.dispose(tensors); 
      }
      frameCount += 1;
      frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrame;
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();
  };
}
```

I updated the `getModel()` to return the model when it is loaded this way we can set it in state.

```
export const getModel = async () => {
  try {
    await tf.ready();
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
      bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights)
    );
    return model;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Could not load model", error);
  }
};
```

So you would then just need to access the `predictions` and render them.

**Edit 1**:

Looking back at the code there are some issues with the `startPredictions` function, you were not actually returning the predictions from the model and you would need to make predictions on a single batch of images at a time.

```
export const startPrediction = async (model, tensor) => {
  try {
    // predict against the model
    const output = await model.predict(tensor, {batchSize: 1});
    return output.dataSync(); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error predicting from tesor image', error);
  }
};
```

**Edit 2**:

Looking at the model input shape [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lowkeyboard/stackoverflow/2ef6b4dbfbf8568ce66d4f8363a1714e1f5c9f02/vModel/model.json) the expected input shape is `(batch_size, 224,224,3)`. But you are passing in an image of `(batch_size, 50,50,3)`. So try updating the parameters `resizeWidth` and `resizeHeight` to `224`.

```
<TensorCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        // Standard Camera props
        style={styles.camera}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
        flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
        // Tensor related props
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={224}
        resizeWidth={224}
        resizeDepth={3}
        onReady={tensors => handleCameraStream(tensors)}
        autorender={true}
      />
```

In addition to that, you will need to also convert the 3D tensor to a 4D tensor before passing it to the model for predictions also known as expanding one of the dimensions. Update the `handleCameraStream` function to this as well.  The size of the tensor is `(224,224,3)` and after expanding the first dimension it will be `(1,224,224,3)`.

```
const handleCameraStream = (tensors) => {
    if (!tensors) {
      console.log("Image not found!");
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrame === 0) {
        const imageTensor = tensors.next().value;
        if (model) {
          const imageTensorReshaped = imageTensor.expandDims(axis=0);
          const results = await startPrediction(model, imageTensorReshaped);
          setPredictions(results);
        }
        tf.dispose(imageTensorReshaped); 
      }
      frameCount += 1;
      frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrame;
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();
  };
```

Comment: it says
Error: When using targetShape.depth=3, targetShape.width must be a multiple of 4. Alternatively do not call detectGLCapabilities()
fromTexture
LOG  prediction: undefined could you help me please? is these about model itself? where can i learn more?

Comment: @caglawayne check the updated answer it is an issue with the `startPredictions` function.

Comment: now i get loop$ with earlier localhost tryCatchs. btw are you able to run the project on your phone? if so can i take look to the repo?

Comment: What does that mean? Is it an error? Yes it works thats why I linked the repo.

Comment: tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.vagustim&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26537:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.vagustim&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26710:32
loop$
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.vagustim&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26537:23

Comment: I mean it works for you model in your repo yes, but is there any chance that it doesnt work for my model because it is a different model?

Comment: @caglawayne I really can't help with such cryptic error messages. Could you at least tell me where and when this error occurs? What is the input shape of your model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234214/discussion-between-cagla-wayne-and-yudhiesh).

Comment: thank you, so then it is safe to say that every tf model will require different methods to integrate the app hence the mistake i made.

Comment: @caglawayne great to hear that. Yes, it gets quite tedious as most people often forget to preprocess the inputs the same way when training the model.