# Error: The shape of dict['ToFloat'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,-1,-1,3], but was [200,150,3]

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Currently building a ReactNative App to detect Objects using the TensorFlow React Native Library.

Not having any experience with TensorFlow, I followed the examples and Guides, setting up the Expo Camera with the HOC of tfjs-reactnative. (https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/latest/#cameraWithTensors)

```
         <TensorCamera
          // Standard Camera props
          style={styles.camera}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
          // Tensor related props
          cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
          cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
          resizeHeight={200}
          resizeWidth={150}
          resizeDepth={3}
          onReady={handleCameraStream}
          autorender={true}
        />
```

I check if TensorFlow is ready and load my Model from a Webserver

```
        await tf.ready();
        const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
          'https://MODEL-DOMAIN.com/model.json'
        );
```

Camera is working and calling the handling function as a callback.

```
  const handleCameraStream = (images, updatePreview, gl) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;

        if (detectionModel) {
          try {
            console.log(nextImageTensor);
            const prediction = await detectionModel.predict(nextImageTensor);

            if (prediction) {
              console.log(prediction);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      };

      loop();
    };
```

Neither *predict()*, *execute()*, *executeAsync()* function on the model succeed to deliver any Result, instead I get this error

> [Error: The shape of dict['ToFloat'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,-1,-1,3], but was [200,150,3]]

Like I said, I'm not really into TensorFlow but a Shape with negative Vector sizes does not seem quite right.

Would appreciate if someone has informations on whats wrong or missing.

Comment: What model is this? Seems like an issue with the model, you would just have to expand the first dimension as @Lescurel mentioned. You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095253/making-predictions-on-live-video-feed-using-react-native-and-tensorflow-js/68101266#68101266) I answered for a similar use case to yours.

Comment: @yudhiesh it's a model my client trained for their business case and exported it for me (json + bin + dict etc)

Comment: So there are `bin` and `model.json` files?

Comment: @yudhiesh yes, correct

Comment: And you get both of them through an endpoint?

Comment: It's a static file endpoint on a webserver atm.

Following the Docs of Tensorflow, if you load the JSON File it will load the .bin Files accordingly from the same Domain and URL path.

At least thats what I read

Comment: Ok but the part where you have to cast the prediction is odd. I've never had to do this. I am thinking this could be because the model is a `tf.LayersModel`. Could you try `const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://MODEL-DOMAIN.com/model.json');`?

Comment: It's 100% a Graph type, it even says that inside the JSON file and an error occurs once I try to load the the model with "loadLayersModel"

Answer (score 2):

`-1` for a dimension indicates that this dimension can vary. In your case (`[-1,-1,-1,3]`), the only constraints are the following:

- Your input must have 4 dimensions
- Your input's 4th dimension must be 3.

Your input only has 3 dimensions. You need to add a dimension to your input (presumably the batch dimension). You can use the [`expandDims` function](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#expandDims) for that.

```
const prediction = await detectionModel.predict(nextImageTensor.expandDims(0));
```

Comment: I see, it wants 4 dimensions while my format only has 3.

I tried the expandDims function which is giving me 

> Error: The dtype of dict['ToFloat'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be float32, but was int32

Comment: After I added a .cast() it did not throw an error, still not 100% sure if this is all correct but this seems to be the right way for the problem