# Error when checking : expected input_1 to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [320,240,3] in react native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor, tensorflow.js

I create a tensorflow model using teachable machine and wanted to implement it in react native. I used cameraWithTensor to take the input here is the camera view

```
<TensorCamera
            // Standard Camera props
            style={styles.camera}
            type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
            // Tensor related props
            cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
            cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
            resizeHeight={320}
            resizeWidth={240}
            resizeDepth={3}
            onReady={makeHandleCameraStream()}
            autorender={true}
          />
```

Here is the `makeHandleCameraStream` function

```
const makeHandleCameraStream = ()=> {
    return (images, updatePreview, gl) => {
      const loop = async () => {
          const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;
          try {
          // const predictions = await model.estimateHands(nextImageTensor);

            const predictions = await model.predict(nextImageTensor); //this is the line where it breaks
            console.log(predictions)
            setPredictions(predictions)
          } catch (error) {
            // console.log(error.message)
          }
            
          requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      
          
      };
      loop();
    };
  }
```

here is the error I am getting when I try to use `model.predict`

```
Error when checking : expected input_1 to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [320,240,3]
```

Tried changes these two lines

```
let expandedImageTensor = tf.expandDims(nextImageTensor,0)

// error encountered without using reshape :
// Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape [null,224,224,3] but got array with shape [1,320,240,3]
            
const predictions = await model.predict(expandedImageTensor.reshape([null,240,240,3]));
//error after adding .reshape : Size(230400) must match the product of shape ,240,240,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68101266/13337635) is another question that I answered that also is about making predictions on live video feed using React Native.

Some things to note:

1. You do not have to resize the tensor as you can do it on the fly using `TensorCamera`'s parameters, `resizeHeight`, `resizeWidth`, and `resizeDepth` in this case set them to `224,224,3`.
2. In the function `handleCameraStream()`, you will need to only make predictions when the model has been set in state.
3. You will need to actively cancel the animation frames using `cancelAnimationFrames` and getting the ids of the frames using `requestAnimationFrame` but I honestly forgot why.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isModelRead, setIsModelRead] = useState(false);
  const [useModel, setUseModel] = useState({});
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(false);
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);

  let requestAnimationFrameId = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameId);
    };
  }, [requestAnimationFrameId]);

  const setUp = async () => {
    try {
      await tf.ready();
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      console.log(status);
      setCameraPermission(status == "granted");
      const newmodel = await tf.loadLayersModel(
        bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights)
      );
      setIsModelRead(true), setModel(newmodel);
      console.log("model loaded");
      console.log(cameraPermission);
      return model;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Could not load model", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUp();
  }, []);

  let textureDims;
  if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1920,
      width: 1080,
    };
  } else {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1200,
      width: 1600,
    };
  }

  const handleCameraStream = (tensors) => {
    if (!tensors) {
      console.log("Image not found!");
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      if (model) {
        const imageTensor = tensors.next().value;
        // add dimension at position 0
        const expandedImageTensor = tf.expandDims(imageResize, 0);

        const predictions = await model.predict(expandedImageTensor, {
          batchSize: 1,
        });
        setPredictions(predictions.dataSync());
        tf.dispose(tensors);
      }
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();
  };

  const predictionAvailable = () => {
    return <Text>{predictions}</Text>;
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {model && (
        <TensorCamera
          // Standard Camera props
          style={styles.camera}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
          cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
          cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
          resizeHeight={224}
          resizeWidth={224}
          resizeDepth={3}
          onReady={(tensors) => handleCameraStream(tensors)}
          autorender={true}
        />
      )}
      {prediction && predictionAvailable()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but this gave me a new error : Argument 'images' passed to 'resizeBilinear' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'null'

Comment: Do I remove the return ? I tried it now it just says image not found 

Comment: Could you help me out by checking the github repo and also how would I get the classname https://github.com/ChinmayMhatre/ml_test

Comment: Ok check the answer again. I have linked a similar one which I have answered in the past.

Comment: Okay I will have a look!

Comment: Hey Thank you this works! Can you Suggest how could I go about printing the result for it? like this is a currency model so How can I display that this is the currency because new data keeps flowing in.

Comment: @ChinMhat ah not sure exactly how you would do it but I added a basic function `predictionAvailable()` for showing the predictions on the screen. Great to hear that please do accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

common format for image input in `TFJS` is **NHWC** (number, height, width, channels) where N=1 for single image and C=3 for RGB inputs

which means you need to expand your input to include first dimension - this should do it:

```js
// add dimension at position 0
const expandedImageTensor = tf.expandDims(nextImageTensor, 0); 
// use it
const predictions = await model.predict(expandedImageTensor);
// dispose at the end to avoid memory leak
tf.dispose(expandedImageTensor);
```

full example using ops posted model in git:
(this is just a quick test using `tfjs-node` but same concept applies in `react-native` that op is using as well)

```js
// git clone https://github.com/ChinmayMhatre/ml_test
const fs = require('fs');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

async function main() {
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://assets/models/model.json');
  const metadata = fs.readFileSync('assets/models/metadata.json');
  const labels = JSON.parse(metadata.toString()).labels;

  const t = {}; // container that will hold all tensor variables
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync('test.jpg');
  t.decoded = tf.node.decodeJpeg(buffer); // in browser use tf.browser.fromPixels
  t.resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(t.decoded, [224, 224]);
  t.expanded = tf.expandDims(t.resized, 0);
  t.results = await model.predict(t.expanded);
  const data = await t.results.data();
  for (const tensor of Object.keys(t)) tf.dispose(t[tensor]); // deallocate all tensors in a single swoop
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    results.push({ score: data[i], label: labels[i] });
  }
  results.sort((curr, prev) => prev.score - curr.score);
  console.log(results);
}

main();
```

i don't know what is model trained on and labels are simply '10', '20', ..., so scores are low using my test input image, but it works.

on a side-node, google's **teachablemachine** is quite old and models are both very simple as well as not very well formed - it works for now, but i'd advise against basing anything on those models.

Comment: I tried this but now I got this error :

Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape [null,224,224,3] but got array with shape [1,320,240,3].

Comment: I tried using const reshaped = expandedImageTensor.reshape([null,240,240,3],[-1]) but now it give me the error : Size(230400) must match the product of shape ,240,240,3

Comment: also tried putting expandedImageTensor.reshape([null,240,240,3]) in the model.predict still doesn't work and gives the above error

Comment: @ChinMat I've never seen TFJS with `null` dimension, it's always an integer.Any chance you can share the model? But it should still accept 0 as input.
Also, next answer is correct - you need to resize image to match what model expects.

Comment: I'll upload the files a github repository could you take a look at it?

Comment: I actually used a model I used in Teachable machine . I uploaded the model files in a github repo here it is https://github.com/ChinmayMhatre/ml_test 
  teachablemachine.withgoogle.com this is what I used to build the model

Comment: i just updated the answer with running code using your model

Comment: The model is basically to detect Indian currency hence the class names . While running it on teachable machine itself gave a low score so I guess you are right. I'll try the above code . But do you have any suggestions how could I make a model made for detecting currency note? like It will Identify which note it is?

Comment: biggest rule for ML is get a good sample data set - so you need at least few hundred different images for each denomination, not just few snapshots using teachablemachine  

second, choose a better image classification model to start with -
i'd go with basic lightweight mobilenet v2 or v3 for something like this, retrain it (not train from scratch) and then save as TFJS graph model (not old layers model)  

there are decent examples on <js.tensorflow.org> on how to retrain a model or how to extend it using transfer learning

Comment: Okay Thank you so much! Really Appreciate the help !!